# Did Sauron purposefully choose Celebrimbor due to his ties with Fëanor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

When Sauron, as Annatar, came to teach the art of crafting magic rings of power, Celebrimbor was the one that he taught.

Granted that Celebrimbor did not know who Annatar really was but is it possible that Sauron (Annatar) knew who he was? Celebrimbor is the grandson of Fëanor, the one who named Morgoth, who committed the first kinslaying, and the one who brought the curse to his family (Curse of Fëanor).

I would imagine that Morgoth wasn't too happy about Fëanor or his family and it makes me wonder if Sauron thought the same way, and chose Celebrimbor on purpose as a way to bring even further misfortune to that lineage.

Does anyone know if it was just a coincidence or was that by Sauron's malicious design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any writing by Tolkien on the question of **why** Sauron wanted to work with Celbrimbor. I'm not sure that there is any reason why Sauron would hate him any more than the other surviving Noldor. I think that more likely reasons for Sauron working with Celebrimbor were:

1. He was the leader of the elves of Eregion.
2. As a descendant of Fëanor, he had an interest in and an aptitude for this type of craft (hence his ability to create the three rings for the elves).

> In Eregion the craftsmen of the Gwaith-i-Mirdain, the People of the Jewel-smiths, surpassed in cunning all that have ever wrought, save only Feanor himself; and indeed greatest in skill among them was Celebrimbor, son of Curufin, who was estranged from his father and remained in Nargothrond when Celegorm and Curufin were driven forth, as is told in the Quenta Silmarillion.
>
> From *The Silmarillion: Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*

Comment: "Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age" in the Silmarillion is where it talks about it. I would also think that other elves besides Celebrimbor could have taken up the craft, if taught. Feanor and his family (Fingolfin and others) made life rather difficult for Morgoth and it made me wonder if that made Celebrimbor more of a target.

Comment: @Rincewind I don't see anything in *Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age* that addresses the question of **why** Sauron might choose to work with Celebrimbor other than a section that describes his skill in the craft of making jewels (the 2nd point in my answer). I'll edit my answer to include that quote.

Comment: The edit looks good. I didn't recall anything in The Sil but I was curious. So, it looks like nothing definitive, only presumption.

Answer (score 7):

There's no evidence for this interpretation.

In fact, reading *Unfinished Tales* it seems as though Sauron didn't choose Celebrimbor at all; Eregion wasn't the only place Sauron was trying to make inroads into, so it seems as though he was simply trying to infiltrate the Noldorin Elves *somewhere*, and Celebrimbor just happened to be most susceptible to his influence:

> Galadriel, striving to counteract the machinations of Sauron, was successful in Lórinand; while in Lindon Gil-galad shut out Sauron's emissaries and even Sauron himself [as is more fully reported in *Of Rings of Power* (*The Silmarillion* p. 287)]. But Sauron had better fortune with the Noldor of Eregion and especially with Celebrimbor, who desired in his heart to rival the skill and fame of Fëanor. [The cozening of the smiths of Eregion by Sauron, and his giving himself the name Annatar, Lord of Gifts, is told in *Of the Rings of Power*, but there is there no mention of Galadriel].
>
> <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 2: "The Second Age" Chapter IV: "The History of Galadriel and Celeborn"</sup>